# Preventing casting when using Inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, casting

I have two interfaces: `IBaseClass` and `IContainer`.

`IBaseClass` has a public property of type `IContainer`.

I also have the following two classes which inherit from `IBaseClass`:

1) `FirstClass : IBaseClass`

2) `SecondClass: IBaseClass`

The following two classes inherit from `IContainer`:

1) `FirstContainer : IContainer`

2) `SecondContainer: IContainer`

I need to access those two containers from outside, that's why I placed a property of `IContainer` in `IBaseClass`. I do understand that I must perform a casting in order to access the fields which are not common to both `FirstContainer` and `SecondContainer`.

However, I do use the `FirstContainer` only when I'm inside the `FirstClass` and the `SecondContainer` only when I'm inside the `SecondClass`.

Since `IBaseClass` is defining the property, when I'm inside `FirstClass` and want to access properties of `FirstContainer` which are not present in `IContainer`, I have to perform a casting to `FirstContainer`.

Assuming `IBaseClass` has the following property:

```
public IContainer ClassContainer { get; set; }
```

Is there a way around it, apart from creating a private member of `FirstContainer` inside `FirstClass` like this:

```
private TheContainer = ClassContainer as FirstContainer;
```

And then use `TheContainer` inside `FirstClass` instead of `FirstContainer`?

**Update**

Here are the classes I created:

**IShapeBase:**

```
public abstract class IShapeBase<T> : Shape
{
    public T ShapeContainer { get; set; }
}
```

**IShapeContainer:**

```
public abstract class IShapeContainer
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}
```

**NewRectangle:**

```
public class NewRectangle: IShapeContainer
{
    public Point BottomRight { get; set; }
}
```

And now, in my `ViewModel`, I have the following:

```
private IShapeBase<IShapeContainer> m_currentDrawingObject;

private void Draw()
{
    m_currentDrawingObject = new NewRectangle();
}
```

This line doesn't compile: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'NewRectangle' to 'IShapeBase<IShapeContainer>'`

It offers me to change `m_currentDrawingObject` from `IShapeBase<IShapeContainer>` to `NewRectangle`, but then there's no point in using `abstract class`.

What can the issue be?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'NewRectangle' to 'IShapeBase<IShapeContainer>'. Thats the problem :-) Look at your definition for NewRectangle, its "public class NewRectangle: IShapeContainer". A NewRectangle is an IShapeContainer, but you are trying assign it to an IShapeBase<IShapeContainer> m_currentDrawingObject. I belive you intend m_currentDrawingObject to be an IShapeContainer. Look, this is all very confusing. Why don't we do like the JS folk and fiddle this at https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Check out my fiddle let me know if it makes sense. without understanding how you've modeled your domain its hard to say. Where are those classes defined (Shape & Point) and how is it all logically arranged and such. https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oZmVQ

Answer (score 1):

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oZmVQ)

You can keep your `IContainer`, however create two sub interfaces such as

```
interface IFristContainer : IContainer
interface ISecondContainer : IContainer
```

These represent more granular interfaces of your First and Second types.

Then in your `IBaseClass` you would need to make the container property a constrained generic type

```
public interface IBaseClass<T> where T: IContainer
{
    T Container {get; set;}
}
```

and when you implement `IBaseClass<T>` it would be

```
public class FirstClass: IBaseClass<IFirstClass> {...}
public class SecondClass: IBaseClass<ISecondClass> {...}
```

Comment: Agree with your proposal, just don't see the need to define more specific interfaces. Once the `IBaseClass<T>` definition is in place, the `T` could be a concrete class for each specification of the interface, which will provide a concrete access inside the class and generalized `IContainer` API for external consumers.

Comment: I tried what you wrote, but it complicated things since I'm using abstract class, I need some implementations. So I edited my question with the entire relevant code.

Comment: @galenus Yes you don't need the more specific interfaces. Its just force of habit you know, decoupling and DI.

Comment: @Idanis check out this fiddle, I threw in an abstract class. This seems convoluted, but its hard to understand what you need without understanding the way you have modeled your domain. It may make sense to you. https://dotnetfiddle.net/8oZmVQ

Comment: @Juan I implemented your fiddle, thanks. I added my relevant code, and I still have an issue, if I'm trying to inherit from `Shape` in `IShapeBase` class. I creates a fiddle with all my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/pWdrVi

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the better way would be:

```
private FirstContainer _container

public IContainer ClassContainer {
    get { return _container;}
    set { _container = value as FirstContainer;} 
}
```

You do not need to return "_container as IContainer" because FirstContainer implements IContainer.

UPD: Cast is required in set in this way. And now you are not allowed to use another class that implements IContainer.

Comment: But then I won't be able to access it externally. I need to access the container from outside of the `IBaseClass` classes.

Comment: @Idanis  ClassContainer property is public. You will be able to access _container via ClassContainer's get.

Comment: I edited my question with the entire relevant code, maybe now it would be clearer.